# spring security: how to configure a set of test data for authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I would like to set some test data username-password, I followed different examples and I used the sequent code in spring-security.xml:

```
 <security:http auto-config='true'>
   <security:intercept-url pattern="/logged" access= 'ROLE_USER' />
   <security:form-login login-page='/login.jsp'/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
 <security:authentication-provider>
  <security:user-service>
    <security:user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
  </security:user-service>
</security:authentication-provider>
```

When I access to logged.jsp page it throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'ROLE_USER'

root cause: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'ROLE_USER' cannot be found on object of type
'org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot'
- maybe not public?
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

isn't just because you have single quotes in 'ROLE_USER' ?

this :

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/logged/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
```